# Javascript - Offest div each time element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been struggling with a simple issue which is a little frustrating. I need a div to move more to the right each time a button is clicked.

```
<div class="gallery">
  //Gallery content here 
</div>
<div class="arrow-m-left"  onClick="moveLeft()">
        //Button to move the gallery left by 590px each time this is clicked.
</div>
<div class="arrow-m-right" onClick="moveRight()">
        //Button to move the gallery right by 590px each time this is clicked.
</div>
```

Comment: Where are your `moveLeft()` and `moveRight()` methods declared?

Comment: The question has been answered now, and im on using onclick anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with the help of jquery **.animate()**.

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/fas3v7hf/1/)

Reference is [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

> HTML

```
<button id="left">&laquo;</button>
<button id="right">&raquo;</button>
<div class="block"></div>
```

> CSS

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #abc;
    left: 50px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    margin: 5px;
  }
```

> JS

```
$( "#right" ).click(function() {
  $( ".block" ).animate({ "left": "+=50px" }, "slow" );
});

$( "#left" ).click(function(){
  $( ".block" ).animate({ "left": "-=50px" }, "slow" );
});
```

You can change the value of left according to your need. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! Thats exactly what im looking for!

Comment: I will do, must wait 4 min first!